# Jquery AutoComplete Displaying Empty Results

Tags: php, jquery

Iam Using Jquery AutoComplete in my PHP 
This is my Main Page code:

```
  $( "#umr" ).autocomplete({
        source:'getpatient.php',
        select: function( event, ui ) {
            alert(ui.item.userId);
            $( "#umr" ).val( ui.item.userId );
            $( "#email1" ).val( ui.item.email );
            $( "#fname1" ).val( ui.item.fname );
            $( "#lname1" ).val( ui.item.lname );
            $( "#mobile1" ).val( ui.item.mobile );
            $( "#insurance1" ).val( ui.item.insurance );

            return false;
        }

    });
```

This is my backend code:

```
 while($rows=mysqli_fetch_array($query)){
$data[] = array(
  'userId' => $rows['user_id'],
    'email' => $rows['email'],
    'fname' => $rows['fname'],
    'lname' => $rows['lname'],
    'mobile' => $rows['mobile'],
    'insurance' => $rows['insurance']
   );

 }
echo json_encode($data);
```

Auto Complete Text Box showing results like this:

[image: This is my autocomplete textbook]

But iam getting results where i checked in alert in autocomplete

Comment: source:'getpatient.php' does this fetch anything ?

Comment: getpatient.php consists of backend code

Answer (score 0):

As a source I add an `ajax request to fetch` the data from the `getpatient.php`

```
$( "#umr" ).autocomplete({


                source: function( request, response ) {
                    $.ajax({
                        url: "getpatient.php",
                        dataType: "jsonp",
                        data: {
                            q: request.term
                        },
                        success: function( data ) {
                            response( data );
                        }
                    });
                },



            select: function( event, ui ) {
                alert(ui.item.userId);
                $( "#umr" ).val( ui.item.userId );
                $( "#email1" ).val( ui.item.email );
                $( "#fname1" ).val( ui.item.fname );
                $( "#lname1" ).val( ui.item.lname );
                $( "#mobile1" ).val( ui.item.mobile );
                $( "#insurance1" ).val( ui.item.insurance );

            return false;
        }
            });
```

Comment: Please highlight/mention all the changes you did.

Comment: @karthik what do you mean script ?You have to get the array with an ajax request and then use it .In addition check if all the requests are correct ,that the `getpatiernt.php` indeed searches the database

Comment: @I.g.karolos iam getting an array and able to see all the results from auto complete text box by checking with alert but my problem is text box showing empty